# HTML Open File dialog box won't work in Android Web view

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

This is my second type of posting this issue since I didn't get a solution on my previous quiz.

I created a web system and I want to open it inside a web view in the Android app. This is my first try at Android Studio. I followed a few tutorials and made up something.

So when I open the app it opens my web system within the app web view.

In my web system, there is a section that uploads images, but when I click it, it won't open and ask for a gallery or camera.

I would like to know how to do it.

I'm using Android Studio for this and these are the current codes.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  WebView webView;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.mysitenamegoeshear.com/");
    WebSettings websettings = webView.getSettings();
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  }
  private class MyWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
      super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
      return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);

    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
      webView.goBack();
    } else {
      super.onBackPressed();
    }

  }

}
```

`This is how it opens in the mobile browser. Here when It clicks to Choose File This pop-up appears. I want to do the same in my web view also.`

[image]

`But when using the web view it won't work`

------------Code update---

This is my HTML view code

```
  <div class="form-group"> @Html.Label("Upload Document", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" }) <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileInputPay" placeholder="Upload Image" >
  </div>
```

Comment: Post minimal html source that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @blackapps I have update the question with the HTML code.